# Place _construct inside a if()

Tags: php, class, oop, constructor

Is there a way to :

```
class foo {
    private $skey;

    if(isset($_SESSION['some_val']) {
       function __construct(){ 
          $skey = 'something';
       }
    }
}
```

I just want to create the initial value of `$key` (something),  if the   `$_SESSION['some_val']`  doesn't exist.

Thanks in advance

**edit:**

this is what I did with your help

```
function __construct() {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['skey'])) {
    $tp = new Text_Password();
    $skey = $tp->create();
    $this->skey = $skey;
    $_SESSION['skey'] = $this->skey;
    }

}
```

Comment: No, you cannot conditionally declare class methods. It's a terrible idea in terms of class design to begin with. Why don't you do the check *inside* the constructor?

Comment: Classes are meant for generic use, usually, so specifically tying it to a `$_SESSION` variable may not be the best way to do things.

Comment: Im doing this, because actually im trying to set the value for $key if it doesnt exist,  then passing it to a _$SESSION variable, then I want to check of the $key was already set, if not I need to generate one.

Comment: Whats the best way to do this Huey ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's impossible. You could do this:

```
class foo {
   private $key;
   function __construct(){ 
      if (isset($_SESSION['some_val']) {
         $this->key = 'something';
      } else {
         $this->key = null;
      }
   }
}
```

Or better, use a parametrised constructor and leave the `$_SESSION` stuff in you main application:

```
class foo {
   private $key;
   function __construct($init = null){
       $this->key = $init;
   }
}
```

Then in your main app:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['some_val'])) {
    $f = new foo('something');
} else {
    $f = new foo();
}
```

Comment: That... method overloading doesn't actually work in PHP. You could do `function __construct($init = null)` to denote an optional parameter though.

Comment: you should have added an explanation about how to do this with a factory and why it might be beneficial

Comment: @tereško Why? As it stands, there is no reason for a factory and I am not the biggest fan of the factory method pattern. Besides, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) it is used when the resulting class of the created object is not known, which is not the case here. If you think the factory pattern is needed here, just post it as an answer.

Comment: @BartFriederichs I said "factory" (as in - separate class, that does the initialization and preparation) and **not** "factory method".

Answer (score 1):

Nope. However, you can simply do this:

```
class foo {
  function __construct()
  { 
    if(isset($_SESSION['some_val']) 
    {
      $this->key = 'something';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just put inside the construct method.

```
class foo {
  private $key;

  public function __construct(){ 
     if(isset($_SESSION['some_val']) {
       $this->key = 'something';
     }
  }
}
```